# Inkscape - rounding corners of shapes?

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape, rounding the corners of a rectangle is easy - you select the object, press F4 (rectangle tool), and drag the circular nodes.

How do you do that for more complex shapes?

[image: polygon, and its rounded equivalent]

"Dynamic offset" is nearly the right thing, but it doesn't round the insides of a concave polygon.

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/88230/path-with-rounded-corners-in-inkscape

Comment: I gave up. Version 1.2 . Too complicated.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Inkscape 1.3+**

1. Select the object with **Node Tool**
2. Click **Add Corners** button in the toolbar. (Icon of rounded corners + 2 dots)
3. Click and drag round nodes on your object
4. You can select multiple nodes and round them all at once

[image: How to add corners to your path]

*OLD Inkscape 1.0 +*

> we have LPE Corners (changer/fillet) this is how you
> apply the effect:
>
> 1. Select object
> 2. Go to **Path/ Path effects**
> 3. Add **Corners (Fillet/Chamfer)** by clicking on **+**
> 4. Adjust the size of corners with the node tool by dragging  green nodes or in the dialog

Comment: This is the answer - all the workarounds on this page are no longer needed!

Comment: in inkscape 1.1 the path effect is called: 'Corners (Fillet/Chamfer)' instead of 'LPE Corners'

Comment: How do you select all the green nodes? I can't select all nodes by doing Ctrl+a or Dragging.

Comment: just select nodes  releted to cornres you want to round and drag a green  handel

Comment: Heh yes path effect are litle obsure we redesing UI  for 1.3 so hopefully they are going to be little bit more discovarable

Comment: In ver 1.2 when I click Path Effects... a large empty dialog box appears. At the bottom is the text "Click button to add an offset". I'm lost. Where are rounded corners?

Answer (score 132):

1. Select the rectangle or square
2. Select the nodes option
3. On the right hand corner, you will see a round node instead of a square node. Drag down the node until you get the rounded corner you want.

The nodes option:

[image: 2. The Nodes Option]

Round widget you need to drag to get rounded corners:

[image]

What happens when you drag the round widget:

[image]

As others have noted this only works on rectangles (but that is a common use case that will land people on this page).

Comment: What is this 'nodes option'? Screenshots would be lovely.

Comment: That's great for rectangles or squares, but how does this help for more complex shapes like the one in the question?

Comment: It should be noted that this will e.g. not export to a DXF correctly. You can use the menu "Path" > "Object to Path (Shift-Ctrl-C)" to create a real rounded path.

Comment: I don't want to upvote this because it doesn't answer the question. On the other hand, the title of the question implies any shape and this is helpful so I upvoted it.

Comment: I think it was the right choice to include this answer, even though it technically doesn't answer OP's question. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed, helpful answer even though it doesn't answer the orig. question.  I guess technically SO would have recommended asking a new question (eg. "how to round corners of rect/squares") and then answering your own question.  You're right that google landed me here and I only care about rectangles!

Comment: When I click the Nodes tool (not option), I get three empty square handles around the rectangle. None is circular. I want rounded edges only on the top two or bottom two corners, depending on which rectangle I edit. Version 1.2 .

Answer (score 53):

This can be achieved using the Fillet/Chamfer path effect (currently only available in the developer version `0.91+devel`, which can be found [here](https://inkscape.org/en/download/#download-devel)). **EDIT** Fillet/Chamfer was removed and reintroduced in 1.0 alpha. As of 2/10/2021, the [latest release of Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/release/) should include Fillet/Chamfer.

**Here's how you use it:**

1. Select the path that you want to modify and then open the path effects tab under `Path > Path Effects...`.

[image: Unmodified path]

2. Add a new effect in the path effects window and select `Fillet/Chamfer`.

[image]

3. Choose a radius that you want to apply to the corners of the path, and press the `Fillet` button.

[image: The filleted path]

4. If you only want to round some of the corners, tick the `Change only selected nodes box` and select the nodes that you want to change in path edit mode before clicking the `Fillet` button.

Comment: This effect seems to be added in Inkscape 0.92 which is not released at the time I wrote this comment.

Comment: Fillet/Chamfer is missing in version 0.92pre1

Comment: @ChristianStrang looks like it's still missing in 0.92 release too :(

Comment: still missing as of Inkscape 0.92.0 r15299 , cant locate the correct win devel build for this

Comment: However, as of april 2017, it isn't available yet, even in development version (0.92.1preX). The feature was moved to milestone 0.93, as you can see
on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170149). Therefore, this can't be achieved by now without building from the [experimental branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/experimental).

Comment: Good news! Fillet/Chamfer is available in 1.0 alpha, which was released. In the description of this video you can find a link to a precompiled Windows version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lFI7qGFP7M

Comment: Works great in 1.0beta2. When browsing the path effects, you have to turn on `Show Experimental` to find it.

Comment: This is the right answer. The Corners path effect does exactly what is needed and is available in the latest release.

Answer (score 20):

This seems to be a weak point with Inkscape, to not have a simple way to do this.  The best way to deal with this I've found so far is:

1. Make several rounded-corner rectangles, using the desired final corner radius
2. Butt them up against each other to make the overall final shape, not minding the spots where corners don't meet due to roundness,
3. Path-union them into one path
4. Fix the extraneous notches by deleting their nodes.

Luckily someone has described this technique online, with illlustrations (scroll down a bit)
 http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=880

I hope there's a path-editing tool that can just convert a path the way you (and fifty thousand other Inkscape users) want, somewhere out there.  If not, this would make a great weekend coding project.

Comment: The link is now broken

Comment: Yup, it's dead. Apparently website URLs have changed, and older stuff is archived.  Try this: https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic72cb.html?t=880    but the images aren't appearing.

Answer (score 20):

Another makeshift solution with issues, but which also works for non-rectangular shapes:

1. Apply *Dynamic Offset* to your object.
2. Convert *Object to Path.*
3. *Add Nodes* (under *Extensions → Modify Path*). This is optional but will most probably improve your results drastically. The more the merrier.
4. Apply a dynamical inset (i.e., negative *Dynamical Offset*) to your object.
5. If desired, convert *Object to Path* once more and *Simplify.*

Comment: see also https://inkscape.org/doc/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html -- inset / offset are ctrl+( and ctrl+), dynamic offset is ctrl+J to add a draggable handle

Answer (score 18):

Here's another method that I've just discovered when I wanted to add rounded corners to an existing irregular polygon for the purposes of creating a laser cut perspex design that is more resilient to cracking.

1. Choose the *Edit Paths By Node (F2)* tool and select the corner node that you want to make rounded.
2. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl-Alt</kbd> and click slightly along the horizontal line away from the corner to add a new node.
3. Do the same again to create a new node slightly along the vertical line to add another new node.
4. At this stage I return to the two new nodes and ensure that they both have a constant offset from the corner. e.g. 2mm away.
5. Select the corner node and press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete it. Your corner should now look like this:

[image: rough corner]

6. Drag the two bezier points at the bottom left so that they form a satisfactory curve. I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and align them on top of each other to look like this:

[image: Aligned]

Comment: Nice solution! One addition to Step 3: I would suggest to use `Extensions -> Modify Path -> Add Notes ...` to add the nodes in order to have the Nodes at the same distance to the edge at each edge.

Comment: This is not so easy however, if your objects' sides are not aligned with the rectangular grid, but are diagonal or slanted in any way.

Answer (score 11):

If your version of Inkscape doesn't have the Fillet/Chamfer path effect, you may find the extension I wrote helpful:

[Inkscape Rounded Corners](https://github.com/hawley577/Inkscape-Rounded-Corners/wiki)

[image: Rounded corners extension example usage]

Comment: I had to read all the above answers in order to reach this answer, but it was worth it. Indeed, this is closest to Fillet/Chamfer LPE. There is also a "Fillet and Chamfer" extension on the official Inkscape page, but it does not work for me.

Comment: I tried it and got [this error](https://github.com/hawley577/Inkscape-Rounded-Corners/issues/5)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I converted my star polygon using using "Object -> Path". It automatically added nodes to corners of the star. Then I selected the star Path and applied radius using "Extension > Modify path > Rounded Corners". [I'm using inkscape 0.92] EDIT: In case this extension makes the edges also rounded instead of corners, just restart inkscape.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thanks for your work on this!

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [bonaccia](https://superuser.com/users/424752/bonaccia) [answer](https://superuser.com/a/885367/388568) (thank You for it) I discovered that to get control over rounded corners You can use some additional rectangle or square and a snipping feature. Check out the following GIF I made.

[image: How to get control over rounded corners]

Answer (score 7):

I have used another method. Once i got used to it, and learned how to use the snapping options, I find that I could work pretty fast. This works best with paths composed by orthogonal lines that are parallel to the axis.

1. Subtract a circle having the radius you want from a square to create a 'cutter' shape. Put the centre of the circle on one of the square corners and size the square as the circle diametre. This ensures that the centre of your cutter will be aligned with the arc edges:
   [image]
2. Duplicate your cutter to be able to reuse it and align it put it on the corner that you want to round. Activate snapping of centres of objects and cusp nodes to align the cutter exactly where you want. [image]
3. If necessary, rotate the cutter along its centre to align the arc with the edges of the underlying path
4. Select the original path and the cutter and do a boolean difference, if your corner is convex, a boolean union if it is concave. Your corner is now rounded!
5. Duplicate the cutter and repeat for all the corners you wish.
6. If your initial shape was open, the boolean operation will have closed it. You may have to reopen it att he end of the process.

Comment: Probably the best solution for now (0.92.2)!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem is to use the path division tool. The advantage here is that the radii can be explicitly set as a number

1. Create the rectangle
2. Create a circle with the desired radius
3. Align the circle into the corner of the rectangle
4. Select the rectangle and the circle, and use Path-> Division
5. Delete the unwanted corner piece
6. Do a Path-> Union between the new circle and the original rectangle

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using the `Edit paths by nodes` tool. I'll show how I handled a single end, but the operation should work for any shape with a flat edge. Starting out with a shape like this:

[image]

Select the `Edit paths by nodes` tool and select your shape. If the end of your shape is flat it should have two nodes, one for each corner. Select those nodes and click the `Insert new nodes into selected segments` button: [image] This will add a third node in between the two nodes on the end, and will look something like this:

[image]

Now that we have a node in the middle we can make our rounded corners. Just select the node and pull it away so it creates a point, like this:

[image]

Be sure to use Ctrl+drag to drag in a straight line. Now that we have a point we need to allow the node to be smoothed out, and this is where the `Make selected nodes symmetric` button comes in: [image]. This adds some handles to the node to allow us to change the shape of the node. It will look like this:

[image]

Now just adjust the handles (holding Ctrl to keep everything straight) to get the desired roundedness:

[image: With nodes selected]

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with just using Bezier curves. E.g. I would draw the OP's L shape like

```
|
|
|
 \
  \
   \_________
```

(very rough ASCII art!) i.e. with a diagonal line where the rounded corner should be, and then adjust the Bezier control points for the two line join points.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Round-Corners extension, that should be flexible enough to fulfill all the cases discussed here.

- chamfer,
- fillet with exact circular arc,
- individual selection which points to process,
- still works when path segments are curved.

https://github.com/jnweiger/inkscape-round-corners

(shamelessly re-inventing a wheel and advertising it)

Answer (score 0):

For a purely cosmetic effect (that is, you don't end up with a rounded path) you could try applying the *Filters >  Blurs > Cross-smooth* effect. Then open the Filter Editor and set the Standard Deviation Effect Parameter to about 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to create a stroke and set the Join and Cap to be rounded. Copy the path and paste in place and remove the stroke from the copy. Then select the original and select path > stroke to path then union the 2 shapes back together.

Answer (score 0):

Enable all snapping:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/budlk.jpg

Perform action from animation using .gif link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n62q.gif

*If anyone can will edit the message to display pictures*

Comment: I might consider editing your answer to include / embed the images, but please first edit it *to include the words!* Actually, I consider the first image to be valueless; I can’t tell what it’s supposed to be illustrating. The second one might be a useful illustration *of a clear list of detailed instructions,* but, IMHO, it’s unacceptable as is. Consider: what if somebody want to print out your answer? It would be useless the way it is now, and adding ***a frame*** from the GIF wouldn’t help.

Comment: After you have edited your answer as per the above, please add a comment that includes “@G-Man”.

Comment: Wow, very CAD!  A lot of effort for each corner, though.

Answer (score 0):

---

#### Its critical that anyone researching this answer reads this

---

Its a shame a bunch of people added a bunch of duplicates and off topic answers. It makes it hard to share new answers that inculdes information that was not available when the question was originally asked.

###### *Anyhow... This answer is about a path-effect that has been a god's send for me.*

##### Rounded Corners Tool (or `path-effect`)

The `Rounded Corners Tool` is a type of tool called a **`Path Effect`**, and since inkscape documentation is terrible ill explain how to access the path effect:

##### Opening The Path Effect

To open the `Path Effects Dialog` navigate through the **Inkscape Menus** as shown in the snippet below:

---

1. Select a single path
2. View the menu-bar at the top off your screen
3. Select the drop-down menu **`Paths`**
4. Read the option until you see the selectable option **`Add Path Effect`**
5. Click on it to open the path effects dialog.
6. The dialog will open like any other dialog.

---

*The dialog is the panel that opens to the side of the window, or opens floating (its opening location is contingent on the configuration that you use, if your instance of inkscape is defaulted it will open pinned to the SVG graphic-design software's window). The **`Path Effects Menu`** is a completely different entity all together, and it is made accessible through the **`Path effects dialog`**. The **`Path Effects Menu`** contains the actual **`Path Effects`** for you to choose from.*

---

7. Now to open the path effects menu, you want to press the Plus button inside of the dialog, it looks like this -> <kbd>+</kbd>, but bigger.

###### *Below shows the `Path Effects Dialog` before a path effect has been added. It should be noted that the blue vector graphic in the image is a ***"Bezier-path"*** that I currently have selected. That path is the path that I am adding the effect to in the image.*

[image]

8. Clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the **`Path Effects Dialog`** will open the **`Path Effects Menu`**.
9. Once the menu opens (it will open in its own window), you will select the **`Rounded Corners Effect`**. Below is an image that demonstrates what the `Path Effects Menu` looks like. Take a look at the highlighted path, as that is the one you will be selecting **—** as stated before it's called the `"Rounded Corners Path Effect"`._

[image]

---

##### You should, at this point, have the Rounded Corner Path Effect has been added to your path.

Select the path that you added the effect to using the path selection tool, which has an icon that looks like this:

[image]

###### NOTE: *The icon may be different, it all depends on the icon-theme your instance of inkscape is configured to use, but the icon will be similar either way*

You can confirm that it was added because a bunch of options will be made available in the **`Path Effects Dialog`**. You should also see green nodes on your path where ever there is a corner.   will have green nodes if you select the `edit path` tool which looks like this

---

### Using the Rounded Corners Path Effect

---

Below is a 3-image set, each image is useful.

#### FIRST IMAGE Image

First image shows an odd object, notice that the nodes are green? The green nodes are Inkscape's indicator that the path-effect is active.

##### Troubleshooting the Rounded Corners Path-effect

- If you have no nodes then you are not using the path-selection tool.
- if you have nodes, but they are not green, then you have failed to activate the path effect.
- If you have only a single green nodes, or the nodes aren't where you expect them to be, its probably the wrong path effect.

[image]

##### Dragging the Green Nodes

To use the path-effect, select any number of green nodes, then drag them. In the image below, I choose an odd shape, the type of shape that is difficult to round symmetrically. It sorta looks like an axe with a point. To round the point I have selected the node, and dragged it back. Before I let the node go, I took a screenshot, this is that screenshot.
[image]

##### The final result.

You will get results as shown below if you follow the instructions correctly

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Since there is no clean solution, let's mention another one, using GIMP!

1- Make a copy of only this object in another Inkscape instance (in case you have other objects)

2- Export to bitmap (a png file)

3- Open the png with GIMP, select the shape by "Select by Color Tool"

3- Select -> Feather -> by `R` pixels (the radius)

4- Color the selection and save/export to png again

5- Open the modified png file with Inkscape and use "Trace Bitmap" tool to get a rounded path (since the shape should be single-colored, it's easy and probably clean)

Comment: There are several solutions listed above. Are they unclean? Taking a vector object to GIMP for editing is a dirty hack.

Comment: @MartinZaske Most of the answers above (that are highly rated) are either limited to basic shapes like rectangles, or they are too much manual and not practical for shapes with too many corners. In complicated shapes I think this approach would be much easier and better than most of the above answers.
Also there was no clean answer when I posted this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the XML Editor in Inkscape to make rectangles rounded corner.  Open the XML Editor, select the `<svg:rect` element.  Add the rx and ry attributes, in the lower right of the XML Editor there are two fields and a `Set` button.  Put `rx` in the top field, and `10` or any other number, then press `Set`.

Comment: In theory a nice idea. Practically, the objects that are mentioned in the question are no rectangles anymore. One can set the `ry` and `rx` attributes but they are not interpreted.

Answer (score -4):

It's very simple actually.

1. Make a shape that has rectangular corners.
2. Click on the rectangle tool
3. Click on one of the circular handles at a corner of the shape, not one of the square handles.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag the circular handle, it will automatically make rounded corners.

[image]
<sup>**Drag a circular handle to make rounded corners.**</sup>

Comment: Unless this changed recently, this should only work for plain rectangles, which is not what the question is about. Even your screenshot shows that you are only selecting the rectangle that constitutes the left part of the shape. Finally, your screenshot does not exhibit the requested inward rounding of concave corners.