# What is the difference between a path and an object?

Tags: inkscape

Please explain to a beginner who is learning Inkscape what the difference is between a path and an object. For example, I draw a rectangle and it is an object. I can then convert it to a path, but it looks exactly the same as before. So what is the difference?

Comment: @random: Why is this not a question about computer software? What is Inkscape if not a piece of computer software?

Comment: Maybe [this chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22759513#22759513) helps you.

Comment: This was closed as off-topic, but https://superuser.com/questions/640954/inkscape-rounding-corners-of-shapes is on the same subject as inkscape usage and was not marked as off-topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inkscape in the stackoverflow site recommends they go into the Graphic Design exchange (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), so perhaps that needs to be done here for these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inkscape features different type of objects, for example:

- Rectangles
- Circles
- Texts
- Paths

So a path is just a one type of object. Paths are special though, as all other types of objects can be converted to paths – they are the most universal representation of vector graphics. In some sense, all other types of objects only serve as a more intelligent and useful way to store information. Therefore, when you convert an object of another type to a path, you are not changing its appearance, but how it is handled.

Take, for example a rectangle. In Inkscape a rectangle is defined by its position, height, width, stroke style and fill style. More specifically, it looks like this (ignore the `style` line, it’s filled with stuff irrelevant for this question):

```xml
<rect
   style="color:#000000;fill:#2cabe1;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.625;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible;enable-background:accumulate"
   id="rect3758"
   width="5"
   height="7"
   x="2"
   y="3"
   ry="0" />
```

When you convert it to a path, it’s instead defined by the positions of its corners and its stroke and fill style:

```xml
<path
   style="color:#000000;fill:#2cabe1;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.625;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible;enable-background:accumulate"
   d="m 2,3 5,0 0,7 -5,0 z"
   id="rect3758" />
```

Now, why anybody would want to save something as a rectangle in the first place? Because rectangles have special properties that ease certain operations. For example, rounding the corners of a rectangle is straightforward. However, rounding the corners of arbitrary paths, in particular if they have non-right angles isn’t (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/640954/203639)). Therefore, if you have a rectangle (the geometric shape) whose corner rounding you might want to modify somewhen in the future, it can be advantageous let it remain a rectangle (the Inkscape object type). On the other hand, you need to convert it to a path if, e.g., you want to move individual nodes or perform operations from path menu.