# Round corners in inkscape for CNC router

Tags: inkscape, vector-graphics

I am trying to prepare some images to cut out with my CNC router. I need there to be no corners sharper than a radius (a little more than the radius of my bit). When I use the built in fillet tool, the not all the radius match. Both outer and inner corners need to be rounded, so I can cut the inside and outside of the shape out of separate pieces, and they will fit together.

[image: The Issue]

Comment: If you select the path tool (F2), you'll notice that the "radius" is not the curvature of the fillet, but the distance to the node where the fillet starts. Which is not good news for your use case.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1375083/65949) contains an extension for what you need.

Comment: Its too bad that extension needs an older version of inkscape to run. Maybe I will develop it for cnc processing. Anything that will work on the current version of inkscape?